# User input from defined list in python

Tags: python, input

I’m new to python trying to code an engineering problem which requires user input of predefined entries. For example I want input of sequence of defined names . say John, Mike, Smith, Adam. I need user to input from this list of names only.
The issue I am facing is user can input any name not in defined list  of names mentioned above. I wanted to limit choice of names to select rather than code an error message that name is not in the list.

Can this input requirement be coded ?

Comment: If the input should strictly be the above-mentioned names then, instead of taking input just give the user the option of selecting the names from the list only

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to do it like this:

```
names = ['John', 'Mike', 'Smith', 'Adam']

name_num = 0
while name_num < 1 or name_num > len(names):
    message = ''.join([f'{i+1}: {n}\n' for i,n in enumerate(names)])
    name_num = int(input(message))
    
name = names[name_num-1]
print(name)
```

This also prints the available choises. The output looks like this:

```
1: John
2: Mike
3: Smith
4: Adam
_
```

If you want to handle bad inputs (no integers) you could also do something like this:

```
while name_num < 1 or res > len(names):
    message = ''.join([f'{i+1}: {n}\n' for i,n in enumerate(names)])
    try:        
        name_num = int(input(message))
    except:
        print('Input must be an integer value')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code you need:

```
name_list = ['John', 'Mike', 'Smith', 'Adam']

user_input = input('Please input a name: ')

if not user_input in name_list:
    print('Please input a valid name')
```

You can then adjust it depending on your case/needs.

Answer (score 0):

Or this:

```
names = ["John", "Mike", "Smith, "Adam"]
print("1 : John")
print("2 : Mike")
print("3 : Smith")
print("4 : Adam")
number = int(input("input the number of the name you want"))
if number == 1:
  name = "John"
```

So on and so forth.

Answer (score -1):

try to take user input first and then loop the check if the user input is available in list or not . if not then raise exception. Show some of your code for more detail.

Comment: Looping would just waste CPU resources. You can use 'in' to check for a string inside a list

Comment: @MercifulSory inputs are by definition blocking the code execution until user input is given. I think any CPU optimization are killed by the reaction time of the user.

Answer (score -1):

You could use recursion. Although, there is a limit for recursion as well. So it depends on your use case. If you want to go for recursion, here is how

```
list_names = ['John', 'Mike', 'Smith', 'Adam']

def func():
    user_input = input('enter the name ')
    if user_input in list_names:
        print("valid user")
        #your code
    else:
        print("Invalid user")
        func()
```

Edit:
The proposed limit for recursion appears to be increasing. Information on the limit and python version can be found at
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0611/